# Unable to streaming RTSP protocol in Andorid Nexus7 and Samsung10 tablets

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp, live-streaming

As per my project requirement I need to load **RTSP** url in videovidew. I can able to display video in some smart mobiles like s3, s4 and sony Xperia. But unable to load in Nexus7 and Sumsung 10 tablets. When I run in nexus7 and tablet10 devices **app is not responding.**

Here is my code.

```
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
mVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

I have a doubt is tablets supports RTSP streaming? if yes, Am I need to change any permissions.?

Please any one suggest me to fix this issue ASAP.

Comment: What does the error listener say?

Comment: Previously we received can't play video error message(my wifi is restricted rtsp protocol but now allowed me to access). Now I am not get OnError, Oncomplete call backs. The loader is continuously loading...

Comment: try adding a [MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html) that will log when called.

Comment: Hi Petey, I am setting setOnInfoListener for video view and I tested in Nexus 7,S3 and Nexus 4 devices. When I used s3 device, we received these cases MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START, MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START, MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END for rendering video stream(working fine). But using Nexus4 and Nexus7 devices unable to receive MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END case[we get only MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START, MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START]. So video is not played in nexus7 and nexus 4. For playing live stream video is there any device specific restriction?? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't found any solution, why nexus and tablet devices are not supported RTSP protocols.

So, for resolving this issue I have moved to ***HLS protocol***. 
I haven't changed/added any code, I just changed rtsp url. And I have checked Http live streaming protocol in smart phones(above 3.0 version) as well tablets. HLS is working fine in all devices except Motorola Defy because this device is not supported videos.

I thought *HLS* is working in above *android 3.0* versions.